# How do I tell Gradle to include a local library jar that in turn has dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, build.gradle

I'm surely missing something as I read the Gradle documentation, since this feels like a common use case. Basically, I have two projects - MyApp and MyLib. MyApp will make use of MyLib.jar as a dependency. MyLib, in turn, has its own dependency jars - when built, MyLib's build.gradle specifies these. In the end, MyLib.jar will contain only the non-dependency .class files, so MyApp will somehow need to download MyLib.jar's dependencies at compile-time.

How do I tell MyApp's build.gradle to include MyLib.jar and then download MyLib's dependency jars without specifying those jars in MyApp's build.gradle? I feel like MyApp's build.gradle shouldn't know about transitive dependencies. I understand that normally, build.gradle will look in a remote Maven/Ivy repo and read the corresponding xml to download the appropriate transitive dependencies, but I don't want to upload MyLib to a Maven/Ivy repository. Ideally, I'd like to distribute MyLib.jar alongside some descriptor file - e.g. pom.xml - that lists the transitive dependencies, but not necessarily packaged as a "repository". See the diagram below to see what I'm referring to:

[image: Library jar dependencies]

Note that I plan on distributing MyLib.jar, not as a set of sources, but as a closed jar, so I don't want to set up a multi-project Gradle build. Furthermore, MyLib's dependencies may either be found in MavenCentral/etc repositories or as jars alongside MyLib.jar in the filesystem.

Comment: Why are you against a multi-project setup?

Comment: @RaGe: Actually, I'd be ok with that, but the second project would contain only a jar - MyLib.jar. It wouldn't contain any source files. Just feels awkward to create a whole project for each first-level dependency like MyLib.jar

Comment: Multi-project is one way, another way is to publish to a local Ivy/Maven repo, so you'd get an ivy.xml/pom.xml that declares the dependencies.

Comment: Your last line sounds line you're ok with distributing a folder of myLib+all its dependencies as jars. You can consume a directory of jars from myApp as `compile files('/path/to/jars')`

Comment: Why you don't want to distribute with a maven repo?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: If I generate a pom.xml alongside MyLib.jar, how do I have MyApp's build.gradle point to it?

Comment: @Phillip For my experience you can't use the pom file in build.gradle

Comment: Did you tought about to use your local maven cache? You can use gradle install for your lib and in your app it will use the "installed" lib from MavenLocal() repo in gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish your library to a local isolated maven repository, and then distribute that repository (for example, as an archive), which can then be used by gradle or maven.

Note: I'm using gradle 2.11.

To create a repository for your library we'll use gradle's [maven-publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/2.11/userguide/publishing_maven.html). `build.gradle` for your library will look like that:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'com.stackoverflow.phillip' // change it
version = '1.0' // whatever

dependencies {
    // ...
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            // uncomment if you want to change artifact id (the default equals to project directory name)
            //artifactId 'my-lib'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'file:local-repo' // path is relative to project root
        }
    }
}
```

After running `gradle publish` a directory `local-repo` will be created. That directory will be an actual maven repository containing only one artifact - your library. Naturally, there will be a `pom` describing your library's dependencies.

Now you can use that repository inside another project's `build.gradle`, for example:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'file:path/to/local-repo' } // path is relative to project root
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.stackoverflow.phillip:my-lib:1.0'
}
```